# In Java8, how to ensure repeated casting is not used?

Tags: java, lambda, filter, java-8, predicate

I have the following filter function in Java:

```
public static <T> void filter(List<T> items, Predicate condition)
{   
    System.out.print("\t");
    for(T element : items)
    {   
        if (condition.test(element))
        {   
            System.out.print(element + " "); 
        }   
    }   
    System.out.println("");
}
```

and I attempt to call this as:

```
List <String> cities = Arrays.asList("Chennai", "New Delhi", 
        "Mumbai", "Pune", "Madurai", "Bhopal", "Bilaspur");
filter(cities, (String str)->str.startsWith("B") ||
        str.startsWith("C") ||str.startsWith("M"));
```

But, I got the following error pointing at **String str** as:

```
incompatible parameter types in lambda expression
```

If I remove the **String** prefix to **str**, then I have to change every **str** occurrence in the chain of conditions as **((String) str).startsWith("B") || ...** which is admittedly lots of verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you're using the parameterized class `Predicate` as a raw class, instead of leveraging generics. You should change `Predicate` to `Predicate<T>`, and then your code will work, and you can remove the `String` prefix.

`Predicate` is essentially like `Predicate<Object>`, so your `filter()` method expects the second argument to be a predicate that operates on `Object`s. However, you're attempting to pass a `Predicate<String>` instead. Since a `Predicate<String>` isn't a `Predicate<Object>`, you're getting that compile error.

Once you change the parameter to `Predicate<T>`, your lambda expression no longer needs to explicitly say `String str`, since by just putting `str` it will automatically evaluate to a `Predicate<String>` using type inference.

Comment: Excellent. I realized Predicate was raw and I should make it generic. But, I was under the mistaken notion that I should touch the source code for Predicate interface. As Einstein said, great things are really simple.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a type parameter to `Predicate`.

```
    public static <T> void filter(List<T> items, Predicate<T> condition)
                                                          ^^^
```

This allows the type checker to infer that the lambda expression in the call must take a `String` parameter.

---

But if you are concerned about the verbosity of a cast, you are ignoring the "elephant in the room".

You don't need to write a 12 line custom `filter` method to do this.  The `Stream` API provides all that you need to do it in about 3 lines.

```
List <String> cities = Arrays.asList("Chennai", "New Delhi", 
    "Mumbai", "Pune", "Madurai", "Bhopal", "Bilaspur");
System.out.println(cities.stream()
                         .filter(str->str.startsWith("B") ||
                                      str.startsWith("C") ||
                                      str.startsWith("M"))
                         .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

The `filter` there is the standard `Stream::filter` method.  The iteration is done by `stream()` and the assembly of a space-separated string is done by the `joining` collector.

Comment: Thanks. But, I wanted to write this example without invoking Streams concept.

Comment: So you are unhappy with the verbosity of a single type cast, but don't care about the verbosity of writing a 12 line method?  :-)

Comment: I was more interested in getting rid of the type-casting. Verbosity was one thing, but more importantly type-casting is generally frowned upon and I wanted to eliminate it.

Comment: Larry Wall, the legendary inventor of Perl had coined the term TIMTOWTDI (There Is More Than One Way To Do It). It's pronounced as Tim Towdy. I am adding your code to my codebase, as an exemplification of this catchy anagram (or abbreviation)?